# while reversing string 'my.name.is' i'm getting output as 'is@.name.my'. I don't understand from where '@' came from

Tags: c++, string, gcc, stack, strtok

Given a String of length S, reverse the whole string without reversing the individual words in it. Words are separated by dots.

Input:
The first line contains T denoting the number of testcases. T testcases follow. Each case contains a string S containing characters.

Output:
For each test case, in a new line, output a single line containing the reversed String.

Constraints:
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= |S| <= 2000

Example:
Input:

i.like.this.program.very.much

Output:
much.very.program.this.like.i

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    //code
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        stack<string> st;
        int siz = s.size();
        char c[siz];
        for(int i =0;i<siz;i++) {
            c[i] = s[i];
        }
        char *token = strtok(c,".");
        while (token != NULL) 
        { 
            st.push(token);
            st.push("."); 
            token = strtok(NULL, "."); 
        }
        st.pop();
        while(!st.empty()) {
            cout<<st.top();
            st.pop();
        }
        cout<<"\n"; 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile on my machine.  `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not part of C++.  `char c[siz];` is not C++.

Comment: @Eljay check this link https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ka5lZW9hip and try for above test case.

Comment: @Eljay It's a GCC header that's [common to see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/327083) in academic exercises and competitions.  It's a mass include of most of the standard library headers.

Comment: When you copy the string into your buffer you don't null terminate it so you get whatever garbage happens to be there. https://ideone.com/LB7P10

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816096/4641116)

Comment: @J... We know what it is but that's not really the point!

Comment: @J... Eljay is not a stranger on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
    char c[siz];
    for(int i =0;i<siz;i++) {
        c[i] = s[i];
    }
```

you don't append a `0` to `c[]` to mark the end of the string.

If you used `siz + 1` as an array size, and put a zero (null character) at the end, it would work.

But still, you should not use VLAs.

Comment: can you share your implementation without VLAs

Comment: `char c[2001];` would do (see problem statement). Or `std::string c(siz,' ')` with `c.c_str()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    char c[siz];
    c.push(0);
    for(int i =0;i<siz+1;i++) {
        c[i] = s[i];
    }
```

You could add a null character to the end of the string and increase the string size by 1 to avoid size violation errors.